# Only one of the cosets of a subgroup is a subgroup.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Show that among the cosets determined by a subgroup S in group G, only one of the cosets is a subgroup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cosets are a partition of $G$, so the identity can only be in one of them.

As an aside, a coset $a H \ne H$ of the subgroup $H$ of the group $G$ may well be closed under inversion, think $G=S_3$, $H = A_3$, $a = (12)$. But it cannot be closed under product, as $a^2 \in a H$ means $a \in H$.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint.* In particular, a coset of $S$ in $G$ is a subgroup if and only if that coset is $S$.

> Both the set of left cosets of $S$ in $G$ and the set of right cosets of $S$ in $G$ contain $S$.  Certainly $S$ is a subgroup, so this is one direction.  If $aS$ contains the identity, then somewhere in $SH$ is $a^{-1}$, but since subgroups are closed under inversion, that means that $a\in S$, so $aS=S$.  Of course, since left and right inverses are the same, an equivalent argument holds for right cosets.